# Is it Possible to Rename Recompose HOC (For Better Stack Traces)?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions, recompose

I love `recompose`, but when I use it I wind up with stack traces that have lines like:

> ```
> in withProps(withHandlers(withHandlers(SelectionOverlay))) (created by withState(withProps(withHandlers(withHandlers(SelectionOverlay)))))
> ```

Is there any way I can give some sort of "display name" to the individual HOC components to get more readable stack traces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `setDisplayName` method available that seems to do what you are asking - https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#setdisplayname

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this section: 
https://github.com/acdlite/recompose#build-your-own-libraries

I believe you can just assign a static property to your component called `displayName` and that will be passed through to stack traces as well as the React chrome extension.

So if your HOC is composed like this, you can just write:

```
const MyComponent = withProps(withHandlers(withHandlers(SelectionOverlay)))

MyComponent.displayName = "ArbitraryValue"
```

Comment: Huh, I tried doing exactly that but it didn't show up in the stack trace :(

Comment: Not sure. It's definitely documented: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#convention-wrap-the-display-name-for-easy-debugging

So I would see there is something else wrapping it. Post code and I can give more insight :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `setDisplayName` all over the place, you may want to try [`recompact`](https://github.com/neoziro/recompact) which aims to solve exactly the problem of awful nesting of `recompose`ed components.

As a pleasant addition, [benchmarks](https://github.com/neoziro/recompact/tree/master/src/__benchmarks__) shows it's a bit faster than `recompose`.